# Scala: Use case for Array.toArray?

Tags: arrays, scala

[Scala.Array](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.Array) includes a function toArray, as an implicit import from [ArrayOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps).

Are there any use cases for Array.toArray or will it always return a copy of the object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ArrayOps` inherits `toArray` from `GenTraversableOnce` (and a default implementation is provided in `TraversableOnce`)

In case of an `Array` it's pointless, but the method is there for all the other subclasses of `GenTraversableOnce`, like `Map`, `List`, `Set` and many others.

Analogously, `Map` inherits a pointless `toMap` method, `List` a `toList`, `Set` a `toSet` and so on.

---

In the specific case of `toArray`, the default implemention provided in the `TraversableOnce` trait is overridden by [ArrayOps](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps.scala#L48).

Calling `toArray` on an `Array` will return a new one only if the runtime class of the destination type is different, otherwise it will just cast the `Array` to the appropriate type and return the same instance.

So, generally speaking, calling `toArray` on an instance of `Array` is useless, although not significantly expensive.

Comment: Thanks. This question came up because I saw this in a piece of code:

def fun(ar: Array[Long]) = ar.toArray.combinations(3).[other ops]

Does is make any sense in this concept? ar will always be of type Array[Long], correct?